# Write efficient update query by joining multiple tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, inner-join

I have a complex requirement to update some records in one table by joining multiple tables to find correct records. I have written the following query which is working but it is taking 2.5 minutes to get executed which is causing my DB connection timeout. Is there a way to improve the efficiency of this query by rewriting it? I have also tried MERGE approach as well which is also taking too long. I have more than 2 million records in EVENT_DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE table and 1 million records in EVENT table and 100 thousand records in CATEGORY table.

```
UPDATE EVENT_DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE eda
SET eda.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = 'claim',
    eda.LAST_UPDATED_DATE = SYSDATE,
    eda.LAST_UPDATED_BY = 'superUsers'
WHERE eda.DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_ID=4002
  AND eda.EVENT_ID IN
    (SELECT e.EVENT_ID
     FROM EVENT e
     WHERE e.PRIMARY_CATEGORY_ID IN
         (SELECT CATEGORY_ID
          FROM CATEGORY START WITH CATEGORY_ID = 495984 CONNECT BY PARENT_ID =
          PRIOR CATEGORY_ID));
```

This is the merge query:

```
 MERGE INTO EVENT_DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE eda
    USING (SELECT DISTINCT e.EVENT_ID FROM (
         SELECT CATEGORY_ID
         FROM CATEGORY 
         START WITH CATEGORY_ID=495984 
         CONNECT BY PARENT_ID =
         PRIOR CATEGORY_ID) CATEGORIES
    INNER JOIN  EVENT E ON e.PRIMARY_CATEGORY_ID = CATEGORY_ID 
    INNER JOIN  EVENT_DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE ed on ed.EVENT_ID = E.EVENT_ID) temp 
    ON (eda.EVENT_ID = temp.EVENT_ID ) 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
       UPDATE SET eda.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = 'claim',
                  eda.LAST_UPDATED_DATE = SYSDATE,
                  eda.LAST_UPDATED_BY = 'superUser'
    WHERE eda.DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_ID=4002
```

Comment: MERGE is probably the best way to achieve this

Comment: Something I always make sure to try in this situation is to `ORDER BY ed.rowid` in your `USING` clause.  In an `UPDATE` with joins, it helps a lot and I suspect it may help in a `MERGE` with joins.  See this thread: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=how-to-update-millions-or-records-in-a-table-200211#5402195700346034590.  I've seen it give a 40-60% improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
update 
  (
    select
      eda.*
    from
      (select * from event_dynamic_attribute where dynamic_attribute_name_id = 4002) eda,
      (select category_id from category start with category_id = 495984 connect by parent_id = prior category_id) c,
      event e
    where
      e.primary_category_id = c.category_id and
      e.event_id = eda.event_id
  )
set
  attribute_value = 'claim', 
  last_updated_date = sysdate,
  last_updated_by = 'superUsers'
```

but I doubt it helps. Generally, that's very very low speed, even if works on old hardware. You should trace these updates and check their execution, affected blocks etc.

First of all, I'd ask you to execute

```
explain plan for <<your update statement text>>;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
```

and write it's result into the question. Yet another... is there any triggers on the event_dynamic_attribute table?

Comment: The problem with this approach is, I always get the following error while executing the query.  SQL Error [1779] [42000]: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Comment: That's strange, it looks like key-preserved. Is event_id is a pk for events? category_id for categories? Is there primary key into event_dynamic_attribute?

Comment: yes, event_id is a pk for events and category_id is pk for categories, event_dynamic_attribute_id is pk for event_dynamic_attribute.